# Rhyming riddle: "Born from gods / Of primordial prowess..."

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Another riddle I made:

> Born from gods
>  Of primordial prowess
>  Loved by god
>  And
> cursed by goddess
>
> Her glare petrify,
>  and hope terrify.
>  Her hair reptile
>  with
> snakes vile.
>
> Killed by winged hero,
>  Her blood birthing
>  A flying
> horseling
>  And a golden titan

Who is it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not really "riddly": no special interpretation of the clues is required, no wordplay/misdirection etc., just straightforward description.

Comment: I could easily see this cluing a password in some escape room kind of thing, so even thought it *is* kinda obvious, and way too straightforward for my tastes too, it has its place among puzzles, which is why I'm voting to not close it. (Which, lacking any other site mechanism suitable for the purpose, is the purpose of this comment.)

Comment: @bobble I have done similar riddles without closure. I see no way whatsoever how this is not a riddle. E.g.: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97186/i-found-myself-to-be-the-fifth-and-a-bridge

Comment: @RewanDemontay that question is so vastly different I'm struggling to see a connection besides the word 'Greek' showing there. Secondly other bad riddles (which I'm not claiming yours is) existing in no way invalidated bobbles point.

Comment: There's some useful discussion at https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5160/what-should-we-do-about-riddles-that-are-pure-trivia. I'm not going to mod-hammer this, but I'm on the "not really a riddle" side for this particular one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's

> Medusa

---

Born from gods
Of primordial prowess

> Some myths cite the gorgons as being children of the primordial deities Phorcys and Ceto.

Loved by god
And cursed by goddess

> Some myths hold that Medusa was a lover of Poseidon, and cursed by Athena.

Her glare petrify,
and hope terrify.
Her hair reptile
with snakes vile.

> She is famous for turning people to stone with her gaze and having snakes for hair.

Killed by winged hero

> Perseus, who was loaned winged sandals and helmet by Hermes.

Her blood birthing
A flying horseling
And a golden titan.

> Drops of blood from her severed head are said to have formed into the mythical beings Pegasus and Chrysaor.